# Memory management for a programming puzzle in java

Tags: java, memory-management

I am trying to solve an interesting programming puzzle

> There are several visitors to a movie rental store and want to rent movies. Each person can rent upto 2 movies. However the rental agency can only rent only 1 copy of each movie.To solve this, rental agency asks each person to give a wish list of movies they want to rent. Each person can provide upto 10 wishes. 
>   Depending on the wish list provided by people, rental agency wants to come up with a solution so that each person can be give a unique movie rental.
>
> Input:
>   A text file containingg of two columns
>   column1 has perosn Id and column2 has the movie ID they wish to rent.
>   There can be upto 10 entries for each person and file may not be sorted.
>
> Solution
>
> 1. Read the entire file line by line and create a map of person vs list of movies requested.
> 2. Sort the entries in the map based on no of movies requested.
> 3. Traverse the sorted list and then assign upto 2 movies to a person from the list if that particular movie is not assigned to anyone else (using a HashSet for this purpose).

This algorithm works for reasonable size of file. But if the input file is very large I get an out of memory error. To be specific, while trying to store the data in the map.
Is there any other approach that I can take? Probably do away with reading the entire file in memory.

Answer (score 1):

> Probably do away with reading the entire file in memory.

Yeah, of course. Read it line by line.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
while(br.ready()) {
    String line = br.readline();
    // do something with line
}
br.close();
```

Now, if your map won't fit in memory, then you have a *very* different issue. But you didn't say that's the case, so I'll assume it's not.

Edit: If you can't store the entire map in memory, use a lightweight and local database like [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite). That's what they're for.

Comment: Yes, the map does not fit in the memory, because it is trying to store all the data. To further clarify, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid storing entire data with any other approach